# Dress code at tennis tournaments on clay

Tags: rules, tennis

Could a player at a tennis tournament on clay wear an outfit (shirt, shorts, etc.) that is the same colour as the colour of the playing surface? Could this be used as an advantage against an opponent?

Are players allowed to paint or dress themselves in the same colour as the colour of the playing surface?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Are players allowed to paint or dress themselves in the same colour as the colour of the playing surface?

It depends. For example, [**Wimbledon**](https://www.wimbledon.com/en_GB/about_wimbledon/clothing_and_equipment.html) (and others ATP Tournaments) has is rules about the dressing code. Also Roland Garros will have a new dress code policy after the [**controversy**](https://www.sbnation.com/tennis/2018/8/24/17779310/french-open-serena-williams-catsuit-dress-code-change) about the Serena Williams suit.

So, you can wear the outfit you want if the tournament doesnt have anything about clothing regulations. If they have, you need always to wear a outfit according with the dressing code of that tournament in specific or you can be disqualified.